# Regex that check if text has the first character equal to @

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will check if text first character is equal to @. So for example:

- @test - this should match
- test@test - this should not match

  I writed something like this: `/(@[\w-]+)/i` but with this regex also second example match but it shouldn't...

Comment: Why to use regex? Isn't better (for performance and readability)  to check if `string[0] == '@'`?

Comment: I must use regex beacause I will it use in my validator in Ruby on Rails application,

Comment: @MateuszUrbański the Rails Guides contain a [Custom Validators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators) section with a validator that checks if a string starts with `"X"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Better than a regexp, you can use for the purpose the `String#start_with?` method:

```
'@test'.start_with?('@') # => true
'test@test'.start_with?('@') # => false
```

But if you really need to use a regexp you have to match the beginning of the string using the the [`\A` anchor](http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/regexp_rdoc.html#label-Anchors):

```
'@test' =~ /\A@/ # => 0
'test@test' =~ /\A@/ # => nil
```

Pay attention to the difference between `\A` and `^`, the former matches the beginning of a string, the latter matches the beginning of a line, so:

```
"test\n@test" =~ /\A@/ # => nil
"test\n@test" =~ /^@/ # => 5
```

This may be the behaviour you want or not.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the starting anchor `^`. This matches the start of  a line.

```
^@.*
```

OR

```
^@[\w-]+
```

Answer (score 1):

`/^@/` is the regex that will only match a string that starts with a @

If you want to capture the string (something that wasn't part of your question), you need to add the brackets:

`/^(^@.*)/`

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to use the `\A` instead of `^`. `^` checks the beginning of each lines in your string. Instead `\A` checks the beginning of the whole string.

this REGEX will do the job: `/\A@[\w]*/`

You can use this online tool to construct your future REGEX: http://rubular.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to find words starting with an @ rather than lines (as the other answer do) you might want:

```
/\s+@\w+/
```

Comment: This regexp matches, for example, the string `test  @test`, that doesn't begin with `@`.

Comment: Actually, it matches the substring @test within the string that you described.  If you read it again, I'm pointing out that it is possible to match words that start with an @ rather than just strings that start with an @.